# Component formula for pullback of one forms

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, derivatives, manifolds

[image]

[image]

Should it not be $\Big(F'(x)v \Big)^j = \frac{\partial F^j}{\partial x^k }(x)v^k$?

Then also how is $F^*dy^j = \frac{\partial F^j}{\partial x^i}dx^i$ derived? I cannot what $\beta_j$ has been taken to be. Surely $\beta_j$ would be equal to $dy^j$ but this does not seem to work. Are we assuming that $F(x)=y$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, it should be $\left(F'(x)v\right)^j = \frac{\partial F^j}{\partial x^k}v^k$

To get $F^* dy^j = \frac{\partial F^j}{\partial x^i} dx^i$, just let $\beta_j$ be the constant function $1$

Comment: Surely $\beta_j$ would be equal to $dy^j$ though? Are we assuming that $F(x)=y$?

Comment: no.  let's hop in a chat. http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18524/1234-differential-geometry